# PHP: check if point/coordinate inside of ellipse

Tags: php, math

How can I check if a Point is inside a Ellipse? When i draw a Ellipse like the this:

```
imageellipse($image, 300, 460, 400, 590, $col_ellipse);
```

How can I find out if the Point x = 100 y = 400 is inside my Ellipse?

RESULT:

```
function posInside($x, $y, $h, $k, $rx, $ry) {
    /*$h = 400; //center x of ellipse
    $k = 960; //center y of ellipse
    $rx = 400 / 2; //radius x
    $ry = 590 / 2; //radius y */
    $part1 = pow(($x - $h) / $rx, 2);
  $part2 = pow(($y - $k) / $ry, 2);
    if($part1 + $part2 <= 1) {
        return true;
   } else return false;
}
```

Comment: This is a maths question. Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse

Comment: Thank you. But how can I implement it in php?

Comment: Well, if you already know PHP give it a try and if you got stuck at any point, ask a concrete question here, sharing your actual code. If you don't know PHP then I'd suggest to hire a developer.

Comment: My Problem is not so extrem with PHP. I don't understand the math form :)

Comment: (*x*, *y*) are the coordinates of the point you wanna know if it's inside the ellipse. (*h*, *k*) are the coordinates of the origin (center) of the ellipse. *rx* and *ry* are the *x*-axis and *y*-axis radiuses of the ellipse.

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much. The function you find in my first post.

Comment: Well done! :) if you want to, it's allowed (even encouraged) to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to @Jordi Nebot for the help with the math form. My Result:

```
function posInside($x, $y, $h, $k, $rx, $ry) {
    /*$h = 400; //center x of ellipse
    $k = 960; //center y of ellipse
    $rx = 400 / 2; //radius x
    $ry = 590 / 2; //radius y */
    $part1 = pow(($x - $h) / $rx, 2);
  $part2 = pow(($y - $k) / $ry, 2);
    if($part1 + $part2 <= 1) {
        return true;
   } else return false;
}
```